# Best way to read file for stbi_load

Tags: c++, stb-image

I'm learning C++ and have been following this [learn openGL](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Textures) tutorial.  I'm trying to geta texture file and put it into data, but I can't seem to get anything to work. What would be the best way to go about this?

```
 unsigned char* data = stbi_load("WHAT TO PUT HERE ", &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);
```

[Image of project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwKJX.png)

Comment: Put the path of image file.

Comment: unsigned char* data1 = stbi_load("C:\\Temp\\RED.png" , &width, &height, &nrComponents, 0);

Comment: @Summit Thank you for the example. I forgot that you need to escape "\" with "\\".

Comment: For debugging you can also use `std::cout << "Error: Failed to load the image because " <<  stbi_failure_reason();` to get more information about why stbi failed to load the image.